# How to run custom scripts post terraform vmware vm deployment?

Tags: terraform

I have been researching on this topic for over a week now and couldn't find any good solution neither on terraform documentation site nor on the web.

Main issue trying to solve right now is: how to run a custom powershell script at the end of terraform vmware basic windows server 2016 vm build.

Tried following methods:

- `remote-exec` - fail
- provisioners inside vm resource definition - fail
- null resource - Error: timeout - last error: http response error: 401 - invalid content type

Here's my null resource definition right below vm resource build within the same `main.tf` file

```
resource "null_resource" "vm" {
  triggers = {
    public_ip = <host ip address>
  }

  connection {
    type = "winrm"
    host = <host ip address>
    user = <username>
    password = <password>
    agent = false
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "userdata.ps1"
    destination = "C:/Windows"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:/Windows/userdata.ps1"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please suggest what are the recommended practices and your working solution

Comment: There's not really enough information here to anwser the question in a useful way. Are you able to make a connection, outside of terrraform, using winrm, to the vm you created, from the machine that's executing terraform?  

What are the errors you're getting back from terraform when trying the remote-exec and file provisioners? Have you tried increasing the terraform log output to see if that reveals any additional information?